How to update requirements.txt file using uv
I'm using uv to manage my Python environment locally, but my production site still uses pip. So when I update packages locally (from pyproject.toml, updating the uv.lock file) I also need to generate a new requirements.txt file. But I can't get that to contain the latest versions.
For example, I recently upgraded packages to the latest versions:
uv lock --upgrade

That command's output included the line:
Updated dj-database-url v2.2.0 -> v2.3.0

And the uv.lock file now contains this, as expected:
[[package]]
name = "dj-database-url"
version = "2.3.0"
...

I thought that this command would then update my requirements.txt file:
uv pip compile pyproject.toml --quiet --output-file requirements.txt

But when I run that, requirements.txt still specifies the previous version:
dj-database-url==2.2.0 \
    --hash=...

What am I missing?

What if you just remove the requirements.txt file first? You could also try --upgrade for uv pip compile.

Oh, deleting requirements.txt first works. Why doesn't it overwrite the existing one? That doesn't seem very intuitive.

Well, in general uv pip compile and the older pip-compile tool don't upgrade dependencies unless you tell them to. Might be related to that.

You can also explicitly https://docs.astral.sh/uv/reference/cli/#uv-export

Ah yeah, uv export would be the correct choice if you want your locked dependencies to be exported – compileing pyproject.toml is another thing.

Thanks both. Adding --upgrade to uv pip compile works, and uv export --output-file requirements.txt also works. If someone wants to write an answer with the options, I'll mark it as correct. I love uv, but all the very slightly different commands baffle me sometimes.
